# El proyecto no se ejecuta y el nombre XXX no existe en el espacio de nombre "clr-namespace:ABC.ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, visual-studio-2019

Les comento el error de mi programa: apenas he podido comenzar agregando una base de datos SQL y luego con ADO.NET creé el archivo Model1.edmx en la carpeta Model. También tengo una carpeta ViewModel con algunas clases.
Para hacer la conexión entre carpetas agregue dentro del código XAML del archivo MainWindow.xaml:

```
  <Window ...
       xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp_Projekt_AnaJaen_MVVM"
       xmlns:localvm="clr-namespace:WpfApp_Projekt_AnaJaen_MVVM.ViewModel"
       ...>
    <Window.Resources>
        <localvm:VMMenueCommand x:Key="vm"/>
    </Window.Resources> ...
 </Window>"
```

El primer error que tengo es en `<localvm:VMMenueCommand x:Key="vm"/>`

> Error XDG0008 The name "VMMenueCommand" does not exist in the
>   namespace "clr-namespace:WpfApp_Projekt_AnaJaen_MVVM.ViewModel".

- El segundo error es respecto a la ejecución del código:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por más que limpio la solución, la vuelvo a construir, reinicio, busco actualizaciones, etc., no consigo solucionar ambos errores. Les puedo asegurar que la clase VMMenueCommand.cs está creada dentro de la carpeta ViewModel.
¿Alguien sabe como solucionarlo y puede ayudarme?

Comment: la tenes pubica a la clase?

Comment: Si. ´´´namespace WpfApp_Projekt_AnaJaen_MVVM
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}´´´